# interepting the proc Ttest in SAS for difference in 2 means

Tags: sas, proc

I'm doing a T-test on a data set with the following hypothesis.

```
H0: mu_inc95(senior)<=mu_inc95(new)

H1: mu_inc95(senior)>mu_inc95(new)
```

Was the senior mean income in 1995 higher then the new's?

My code is this:

```
proc ttest data=c2 ;

var  inc95;

class seniority;

run;
```

And I get the following results:
[image]
http://srv1.jpg.co.il/2/52c2c92d39500.png

I can see that for the F test for VAR, the p.v. is 0.5320 so they are equal.

But the p.v. for the ttest is 0.66 which means I approve the null hypothesis.
But  it is obviously wrong.

Am I looking on the p.v. wrong?

Comment: This isn't really a question about SAS. It sounds like you're more confused by the interpretation of p-values than by SAS, so you might want to try posting on http://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: All of your P values are insignificant. Therefore, you have not found a statistically significant relationship.